# How to embed a survey on my page with real-time result graph after each answer?

Tags: graph, real-time, survey

I would like to embed a survey on my page so that I have a graph showing after each answered question. The graph would include that answer as well. Is there an engine that allows me to do this or is it easier to write the script myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for real-time broadcast updates take a look at http://www.realtime.co/developers/demos/demo/poll built using the Realtime Framework (the company I work for).